Mapping of points in 2d plane.
Consider the following scenario. If I have $2$ arrays with $arr1 = ((37,95),(73,59),(15,15),(5,86),(60,70),(2,96),(83,21),(18,18),(30,52),(43,29))$ and $arr2 = ((12,49),(3,90),(25,66),(31,52),(54,18),(96,77),(93,89),(59,92),(8,19),(4,32))$. I would like to find a relation or a mathematical function $F$ such that $F(arr1) = arr2$? I tried using polynomial regression but I am not satisfied with the answer. The reason is that this approach tries to map point $1$ of $arr1$ with point $1$ or $arr2$ i.e. corresponding points, but what I wanted is any point of $arr1$ can be mapped to any single point in $arr2$ while also find the relation between them. Any leads on how to do it?
